# What is the definition of climb gradient?

Tags: climb

I have a hard time understanding this topic. I understand it’s the percentage of rising over horizontal distance. Is that correct?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Comment: For small climb, climb gradient in decimal is almost equivalent to angle of climb in rad (40% gradient has only 5% error in this conversion)